# How to restructure this bit of code?

Tags: c#

I'm designing a simple calculator using Visual C# but I'm running into an annoying runtime error (which is funny for a statically typed language).

First let me show you the partial code:

```
private float get_input()
{
    try
    {
        return float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch
    {
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox2.AppendText("Invalid Input");
        return 0;
    }

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    textBox2.Clear();
    float v = get_input();
    textBox2.AppendText((Math.Sin(v)).ToString());
}
```

The problem is that when I run the program, and let's say for example, I enter "a" into the input box, my program *does* handle the exception by displaying "Invalid input" into the output box. However, it then proceeds to calculate the `sin` or `cos` (etc) of the default float type. So the answer in the output box would look like: "invalid input1" or "invalid input0". I provided a screenshot:

[image]

I do realize this is because I'm telling it to append text right after I call the `get_input()` method, but I really don't know how to find a way around this. I've tried restructuring my code in like 7 ways but something always goes wrong.

Comment: You really don't know how to have method get_input indicate that it failed, so the caller can decide not to run the calculation? I can think of at least 3 ways.

Comment: Use `float.TryParse`, which will return true if successful or false if not (no need to throw an exception), and then do the calculation only if the try parse returns true.

Comment: You could have your method return a `string`, and then parse/handle it in your `click` event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use TryParse instead of try...catch

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    textBox2.Clear();
    float result;
    if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out result))
    {
         textBox2.AppendText(Math.Sin(result).ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        textBox2.Text = "Invalid Input";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have no way of telling the calling code that an error has occurred.

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Trap the exception as now but change the return type to a nullable float (`float?`) and set it to `null` in the error case:

   ```
   private float? get_input()
   {
       try
       {
           return float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
       }
       catch
       {
           textBox2.Clear();
           textBox2.AppendText("Invalid Input");
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you have to trap that condition:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
       textBox2.Clear();
       float? v = get_input();
       if (v != null) textBox2.AppendText((Math.Sin(v)).ToString());
   }
   ```
2. Let the exception propagate up to your button click code. In this case your `get_input` method becomes a one liner and can be removed:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
       textBox2.Clear();
       try
       {
           float v = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
           textBox2.AppendText((Math.Sin(v)).ToString());
       }
       catch
       {
           textBox2.Clear();
           textBox2.AppendText("Invalid Input");
       }
   }
   ```

Both approaches are OK, but the second is cleaner.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!! I actually thought about trying to tell my code that an error occurred by setting a Boolean like bool errorFound = false; but it then lead to complicated issues when I had to switch between true and false cause once it became false, all other calculations failed

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? I don't see the need for a separate function in such a simple scenario.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    textBox2.Clear();
    try
    {
        float v = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        textBox2.AppendText(Math.Sin(v).ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        textBox2.AppendText("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

If you want to have a separate function, you could do it this way:

```
private float? try_get_input()
{
    try
    {
        return float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    textBox2.Clear();
    float? v = try_get_input();
    if (v != null)
    {
        textBox2.AppendText(Math.Sin(v.Value).ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        textBox2.AppendText("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case an exception is thrown in the parsing function `get_input`, a value of `0` is returned. However, the calling function `button1_Click` has no means to known that the exception was thrown in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
private bool try_get_input(out float val)
{
    val = 0;

    try
    {
        val = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox2.AppendText("Invalid Input");
    }

    return false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    textBox2.Clear();

    float v = 0;

    if (try_get_input(out v))
    {
        textBox2.AppendText((Math.Sin(v)).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Simply use `float.TryParse()` instead.

Comment: Hehe. Fair enough. I was trying to stay within the bound of the code he had.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not really give an indication in `get_input` that something failed. I propose two approaches to solve the problem:

1. Work with **`NaN`**. `NaN` stands for *Not-a-Number*. It is for instance used if you calculate the arcsin of *2.0*. Normally a `NaN` propagates through every expression. You then detect it in your `button1_Click` method:

   ```
   private float get_input() {
       try {
           return float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
       }
       catch {
           textBox2.Clear();
           textBox2.AppendText("Invalid Input");
           return float.NaN;
       }
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
       textBox2.Clear();
       float v = get_input();
       if(v != float.NaN) {
           textBox2.AppendText((Math.Sin(v)).ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
2. The method I think is the based is to use a **higher order method**: a method for which you provide a delegate:

   ```
   private void calculateResult (Func<float,float> f) {
       textBox2.Clear();
       try {
           float v = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            textBox2.AppendText((f(v)).ToString());
       }
       catch {
           textBox2.AppendText("Invalid Input");
           return float.NaN;
       }
   }
   ```

   Now can you call that method by simply providing a reference to `Math.Sin` using a *lambda expression*:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
       calculateResult(x => (float) Math.Sin(x));
   }
   ```

   Furthermore it is an elegant solution, because you can easily enumerate over all the functions you want to implement:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
       calculateResult(x => (float) Math.Sin(x));
   }

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
       calculateResult(x => (float) Math.Cos(x));
   }

   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
       calculateResult(x => (float) Math.Tan(x));
   }
   ```

   You thus *reuse code* in this approach. Which makes the code easier to debug.